# Trocando componentes em tempo de execução no Ionic 3

Tags: ionic, typescript, framework

Boa tarde, é minha primeira pergunta aqui no fórum.

Tenho uma duvida, e nem sei como pesquisar, sou inciante no Ionic 3. Gostaria de saber de tem como por exemplo:

Tenho uma pagina, quando ela carrega abre um alert do tipo confirme, gostaria que ao clicar no SIM carregasse um form na mesma pagina é possível?

E tem como bloquear, tipo um disabled no clique fora do alert?

Desde já obrigado pelo tempo e pela boa vontade!

Comment: Um bom lugar pra começar é a documentação dos [componentes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components)  e do próprio [alert ](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert). Lá indica qual flag usa pra não dar dismiss quando clica no backdrop e tbm tem exemplo de handler dos botões.

Comment: Leonardo Lima - consegui com esta opção -> enableBackdropDismiss: false dentro do alert no meu arquivo .ts.. agora falta conseguir carregar o form dentro do handle.. Obrigado..

Answer (score 0):

Assim como mencionado pelo @LeonardoLima, você pode usar o `AlertController` fornecido pelo próprio Ionic usando o `enableBackdropDismiss` como `false`. Quanto a você exibir o formulário ao clicar em `Sim`, você pode usar as diretivas do Angular, no seu caso, o `ngIf`.

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
// HTML

// Esse formulário é exibido se, e apenas se, o valor de "exibirFormulario" for verdadeiro.
// Do contrário, ele é escondido do DOM
<form *ngIf="exibirFormulario">
 // O conteúdo do form
</form>
```

```
// No arquivo .ts dessa página

/**
 * Diz se deve exibir o formulário
 */
public exibirFormulario: boolean = false;

/** 
 * Método executado quando o usuário entra na página
 */
public ionViewDidEnter(): void {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirma a ação',
    message: 'Você quer abrir o formulário?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Não',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Formulário não foi aberto.');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Sim',
        handler: () => {
          // Ao marcar como verdadeiro, você diz para o Angular exibir 
          // aquele trecho de código dentro do ngIf.
          this.exibirFormulario = true;
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Eu recomendo a documentação do [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) para você se aprofundar mais sobre o assunto.

Uma dica, quando for estudar Ionic, em essência, você estuda Angular, então procure vídeos sobre Angular que irá servir o mesmo propósito que estudar Ionic.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção Vinicius Lourenço. Vou aplicar aqui este código. Obrigado pelas dicas, vou segui-las!